# Custom html elements and Angular

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have to integrate third-party elements into my Angular(4.3.x) application. They look something like:

```
<any-widget id="123"></any-widget>
```

I already made Angular produce no error by adding `schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]` to app.module.ts. But unfortionally i can't but anything to it. I tried:

```
<any-widget [id]="id"></any-widget>
```

and

```
<any-widget id="{{id}}"></any-widget>
```

But id is not displayed at all. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<any-widget [attr.id]="id"></any-widget>
```

or

```
<any-widget attr.id="{{id}}"></any-widget>
```

Without `attr.` Angular tries to bind to a property of an HTML element, or an `@Input()` of an Angular directive. If none of these exists with the used name, you need to use attribute binding.

Comment: Wohooo thanks so much!